# trouble setting variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables

I am getting errors on variables `FaxPro`, `EmailPro`, `FaxStat`, and `EmailStat`.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string CustNo = reader["CUSTNO"].ToString();
    string Phone = reader["PHONE"].ToString();
    string Fax = reader["FAX"].ToString();
    string Email = reader["PRI_EMAIL"].ToString();
    string Type = reader["TYPE"].ToString();

    if (Type.Contains("H"))
    {
        if (Type.Contains("F"))
        {
            string FaxStat = "Y";
            string FaxPro = "PENDING";
        }
        else
        {
            string FaxStat = "N";
            string FaxPro = "NONE";
        }
        if (Type.Contains("E"))
        {
            string EmailStat = "Y";
            string EmailPro = "PENDING";
        }
        else
        {
            string EmailStat = "N";
            string EmailPro = "NONE";
        }
//outbox
// id, account, type, title, number, fax, email, faxpro, emailpro, faxstat, emailstat, filepath, datesent

        MySqlCommand mycommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO outbox (id, account, type, title, number, fax, email, faxpro, emailpro, faxstat, emailstat, filepath, datesent) VALUES('0','" + CustNo + "', 'CUSTOMER', 'test', '" + Phone + "', '" + Fax + "', '" + Email + "', '" + FaxPro + "', '" + EmailPro + "', '" + FaxStat + "', '" + EmailStat + "', 'test', NOW())", conn);
  mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Errors are:

> The name 'FaxPro' does not exist in the current context C:...\Form2.cs

... and so on for `EmailPro`, `FaxStat`, and `EmailStat`.

Comment: Your variables are out of scope - they only exist between the {braces} in which they were declared.  Please read up on [variable scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: You should lowercase your variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of the variables is out of scope. They are declared in the if statement. Move the declaration to an outer scope like that:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{ 
    string CustNo = reader["CUSTNO"].ToString(); 
    string Phone = reader["PHONE"].ToString(); 
    string Fax = reader["FAX"].ToString(); 
    string Email = reader["PRI_EMAIL"].ToString(); 
    string Type = reader["TYPE"].ToString(); 

    string FaxStat = string.Empty;
    string FaxPro = string.Empty;
    string EmailStat = string.Empty; 
    string EmailPro = string.Empty; 
    if (Type.Contains("H")) 
    { 
        if (Type.Contains("F")) 
        { 
            FaxStat = "Y"; 
            FaxPro = "PENDING"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            FaxStat = "N"; 
            FaxPro = "NONE"; 
        } 
        if (Type.Contains("E")) 
        { 
            EmailStat = "Y"; 
            EmailPro = "PENDING"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            EmailStat = "N"; 
            EmailPro = "NONE"; 
        } 
        //outbox 
        // id, account, type, title, number, fax, email, faxpro, emailpro, faxstat, emailstat, filepath, datesent 

        MySqlCommand mycommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO outbox (id, account, type, title, number, fax, email, faxpro, emailpro, faxstat, emailstat, filepath, datesent) VALUES('0','" + CustNo + "', 'CUSTOMER', 'test', '" + Phone + "', '" + Fax + "', '" + Email + "', '" + FaxPro + "', '" + EmailPro + "', '" + FaxStat + "', '" + EmailStat + "', 'test', NOW())", conn); 
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare your strings in the beginning of your function, so they have scope all throughout. At the moment, you're declaring `FaxPro, EmailPro, FaxStat, EmailStat` inside your `if/else` statement blocks, and once that block ends, they go out of scope.

By declaring them once at the beginning of your function you will avoid declaring them multiple times in your `while` loop.

```
//small example
public void myFunc()
{
    string CustNo, Phone, Fax, Email, Type, FaxStat, FaxPro, EmailStat, EmailPro;

    //set up query and reader
    //...
    while(reader.read())
    {
         CustNo = reader["CUSTNO"].ToString();
         //etc.
    }
    //reader.close(); conn.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string CustNo = reader["CUSTNO"].ToString();
    string Phone = reader["PHONE"].ToString();
    string Fax = reader["FAX"].ToString();
    string Email = reader["PRI_EMAIL"].ToString();
    string Type = reader["TYPE"].ToString();
    // Declare your variables here
    string FaxStat, FaxPro, EmailStat, EmailPro;

    if (Type.Contains("H"))
    {
        if (Type.Contains("F"))
        {
            FaxStat = "Y";
            FaxPro = "PENDING";
        }
        else
        {
            //...
            //...
```

Comment: You shouldn't redeclare the variables. `string FaxState = "Y";`

Comment: Thank you! I started out using PHP.  Which I think allows you to get away with a lot.  But, C# is forcing me to learn programming the way I should have from the beginning.